# View unresponsive after AVPlayerViewController dismissed - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a parent view with a play button that instantiates an AVPlayerViewController object. If the user presses the player's default "Done" button, the player view disappears and the parent view works as expected. However, when playback finishes by reaching the end of the video, the player disappears but the parent view screen is unresponsive to button clicks. I don't understand because both scenarios are using the same callback to dismiss the player view.

Here is the code where I instantiate the AVPlayer and set up the two notifications for how the playback can be completed:

```
func playVideoLocally() {
    // create player
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(URL: NSURL(string: media.url)!))
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    // create modal view with callback for done button
    // This works fine
    playerController = CustomAVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    playerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "onLocalPlayCompletion:",
        name: CustomAVPlayerViewController.viewWillDisappearNotification,
        object: nil)
    self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // create player completion callback
    // This leads to unresponsive parent view
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onLocalPlayCompletion:",
        name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
        object: playerItem)

    // play it
    player.play()
}
```

Here is my onLocalPlayCompletion callback that both scenarios are calling:

```
func onLocalPlayCompletion(note: NSNotification) -> Void {
    playerController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    onCompletion()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The only reason why pressing "Done" wasn't affecting the parent view is because it's using a default AVPlayer action to dismiss itself. My attempt to dismiss the player from inside onLocalPlayCompletion(),

```
playerController.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

isn't correct, and in my case I replaced it with

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

which does what I want.